# Correct way to copy dictionary returned by function

Tags: c#, dictionary

I´m using C# and have the following function:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetData(string fileName)
{
     Dictionary<string, string> returnDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

     .... Load data from file into dictionary........

     return returnDictionary;
}
```

What is the correct way to use the returned dictionary:

```
public class WhateverClass
{
     Dictionary <string, string> classDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

     ... Class code....

     public void WhateverFunction ()
     { 
           ...

           // SHALL I USE

           classDictionary = GetData(filename);

           ...

           // OR
           classDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>(GetData(filename));
     }
}
```

What should be the proper use of the returned dictionary, copying it to an already created dictionary in my class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider getting rid of your class level variable based upon the usage. Scope the dictionary correctly.

If you are going to be continuously writing over your class dictionary within different method calls, then it probably should not be a class level variable.

As for generating the dictionary, there is no need to call `classDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>(GetData(filename));` because your method already creates a new dictionary. Essentially you're creating a new dictionary then copying it and throwing away what you made.

Just use `classDictionary = GetData(filename);`

Comment: And if you're not continuously overwriting it, but you want to use it everywhere, then just initialize it with `GetData()` in the first place.

Comment: I would actually tend to disagree. Perhaps this dictionary needs to not be null, but is ok to be empty until it is initialized in `WhateverFunction` and GetData cannot be called on class instantiation.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree, I hadn't addressed part of the question which is why I edited it. :)

Comment: I need the dictionary to be empty on class constructor (otherwise access to it will return an exception). After application full load, I will then read the file and populate it. The dictionary can be accessed at any time, even before the data is loaded. My worry is if issuing classDictionary = GetData(filename) I won´t be leaving unnecesserely 2 dictionaries around insted of one...

Comment: @Mendez, Perhaps calling `WhateverFunction` "Init" or something similar would help alleviate confusion like this in the future. Methods like that are expected to be called only once. Generically named method could be called over and over again, leading to @DanielCook's observations.

Comment: Whatever function is indeed an init function... But this is not the point of the question... I want to emphasize the copy method, not how often am I calling it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to reconstruct the dictionary, the existing reference will be more than sufficient.

C# uses a reference-count based garbage collector. By returning (and assigning the return value) the dictionary, you add to the reference count. Until that reference (and all other references) go out of scope, you can use the dictionary with no worries.

Of course, without a reference it would be hard to use the dictionary in the first place :).

Very rarely do you actually need to perform a deep copy, and the code you posted doesn't seem to warrant it here.

Comment: So, what happens to the first created dictionary when I turned classDictionary to be the returned one created on the static class ? Will it be left for garbage collector or destroyed immediately ?

Comment: It will be left for the garbage collector (assuming nothing else got  a reference to it). If it is small (gen0) it will be picked up fairly quickly, but there is no way to guarantee when. Even calling GC.Collect is just a suggestion. You shouldn't need to worry about it though.